# How to leave flushbar on call navigation pop?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flushbar

I'm using another_flushbar to show notifications and also from sockets connected notification that delivered in parallel. But this notification is prevent to pop call or press back button on screen, because of I see it is using pop on common navigator to close notification. How can I avoid it?
I want to back from page by pop call or press back button, but leave the message on screen (and close it automatically by duration). So I need somehow to make it parallel.
I found [follow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664760/flutter-draw-flushbar-over-any-buildcontext), but it looks obsoleted and I have no idea how to use it for last version of flutter.
My code (to reproduce the issue open second page, show flushbar (it will shows for 10 seconds), press back button - it will close the notification instead of go back to the first screen):

```
    import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('go to second screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const SecondScreen()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('show flushbar'),
          onPressed: () {
            MyFlushbar.show(
              context: context,
              text: "test message",
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFlushbar {
  static show({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String text,
  }) {
    Flushbar(
      message: text,
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.check_circle,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.GROUNDED,
    ).show(context);
  }
}
```